# Mysql select LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

I have a column in mysql table named category.

```
Clothese category is 1
Mens clothes is 1-1
Ladies clothes is 1-2
Kids clothes is 1-3
```

The goal for above structure is to easily load all clothes in one page with below query.

```
$cat=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[cat]); 
$query="select * from campaigns WHERE category LIKE '$cat%' ";
```

Till here it works fine but the problem is I have another category with ID 10 for perfumes, When I want to load category 1 (including 1 itself and it's sub-categories like 1-1 ) it's loading category 10 as well.

Please let me know what is the proper solution

Comment: can "select * from campaigns WHERE category LIKE '{$cat}-%' " solve your problem for perfumes ` LIKE '10-%'`

Comment: Save yourself some time and rewrite the application to not use the `mysql_*` family of functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I applied your code and both URLs below are not loading any product

products.php?cat=10 
products.php?cat=10-

Answer (score 1):

query can be for:1-1,1-2

```
$query="select * from campaigns WHERE category LIKE '$cat-%' ";
```

Same will work for 10 also
Edit:

```
$query1=mysql_numrows("select * from campaigns WHERE category LIKE '$cat-%' ");
if($query1>0) $str="-"
else $str="";
$query_final=mysql_query("select * from campaigns WHERE category LIKE '$cat$str%'");
```

Comment: This is not workable as for example for category 10 we don't have 10-1 and like this